# Creating a large surjective dictionary without repeated elements?

Tags: function-construction, associations, dictionary

I would like to have a surjective dictionary that saves the following associations

```
{a[1]->a[1]+a[2]+..., a[2]->a[1]+a[2]+..., ...,
 b[1]->b[1]+b[2]+..., b[2]->b[1]+b[2]+..., ...,
 ...}`
```

So basically, each element `a[i]` or `b[i]` etc refers to the sum of all `a[i]` or `b[i]` etc respectively. Clearly, there is no need to save the sum `a[1]+a[2]+...` for each `a[i]` key separately, since they are always the same. Is there a way to save it only once and instead provide some sort of "pointer" to it in the dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. We start with a very redundant association `rules`.

```
n = 1000;
rules = Association[
  Join @@ Map[Thread[# -> Total[#]] &, {Array[a, n], Array[b, n]}]
  ];
```

Next, we find the *set* of all values and create an `Association` named `valuetable` with consecutive integers as keys. (We could also use a simple `List` for that.) Afterwards, we look up which "pointer" key to assign to the keys in `rules`, store that in `keytable` and create a rudimentary query function `dictionary` which would look like the actual dictionary for the user.

```
With[{duplicatefreevals = DeleteDuplicates[Values[rules]]},  
  valuetable = AssociationThread[
    Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]], 
    duplicatefreevals
    ];
  keytable =  With[{
    repo = AssociationThread[
      duplicatefreevals,
      Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]]
      ]
    }, 
    AssociationThread[Keys[rules], Lookup[repo, Values[rules]]]
    ];
  ];
dictionary[query_] := valuetable@keytable@query;
```

Let's compare the `ByteCount`s:

```
ByteCount[rules]
ByteCount[valuetable] + ByteCount[keytable]
```

> 144810376
>
> 512992

We can access, e.g. the entry of `a[6]` by `dictionary[a[6]]`.

There is also a slightly different that exploits that `Association` has the attribute `HoldAllComplete`. The only tweak, is that we map `valuetable` over `Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]]` *before* we define `valuetable`. This way, we can call `keytable` now `dictionary` are skip the definition of the query function:

```
With[{duplicatefreevals = DeleteDuplicates[Values[rules]]},
  ClearAll[valuetable];
  dictionary = With[{
     repo = 
      AssociationThread[
       duplicatefreevals, 
       valuetable /@ Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]]]
     },
    AssociationThread[Keys[rules], Lookup[repo, Values[rules]]]
    ];
  valuetable = 
   AssociationThread[
    Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]], 
    duplicatefreevals
    ];
  ];
dictionary // Short
```

On the **pro side**: We can put queries to `dictionary` in the same way as for every other `Association` without further coding.

On the **con side**: `dictionary` is a tiny bit bigger than before:

```
ByteCount[dictionary] + ByteCount[keytable]
```

> 831600

More importantly, it may be not as robust since, e.g., `Map`ing anything onto `dictionary` will evaluate values; I am not sure if this is always desireable...

**Edit**

The OP had the very good idea to also write an interface for appending entries subsequently. I take the freedom to incorporate this in a data type `dictionary`:

```
ClearAll[dictionary]
SetAttributes[dictionary, HoldAll];
toDictionary[rules_] := Module[{$dictionary},
   $dictionary = 
    With[{duplicatefreevals = DeleteDuplicates[Values[rules]]},
     With[{repo = 
        AssociationThread[duplicatefreevals, 
         Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]]]},
      Association[
       "ValueTable" -> 
        AssociationThread[Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]], 
         duplicatefreevals],
       "ValueIndex" -> 
        AssociationThread[duplicatefreevals, 
         Range[Length[duplicatefreevals]]],
       "KeyTable" -> 
        AssociationThread[Keys[rules], Lookup[repo, Values[rules]]]
       ]
      ]
     ];
   dictionary[$dictionary]
   ];

dictionary /: dictionary[$dictionary_][query__] := With[{
    keytable = $dictionary[["KeyTable"]],
    valuetable = $dictionary[["ValueTable"]]
    },
   valuetable[keytable[query]]
   ];

dictionary /: ByteCount[dict : dictionary[$dictionary_]] := 
  ByteCount[$dictionary];

dictionary /: associateTo[dictionary[$dictionary_], key_ -> value_] :=
   With[{
    pos = ($dictionary[["ValueIndex"]])[value]
    },
   If[MissingQ[pos],
    With[{i = Length[$dictionary[["ValueTable"]]] + 1},
     AssociateTo[$dictionary[["ValueTable"]], i -> value];
     AssociateTo[$dictionary[["ValueIndex"]], value -> i];
     AssociateTo[$dictionary[["KeyTable"]], key -> i];
     ],
    AssociateTo[$dictionary[["KeyTable"]], key -> pos];
    ]
   ];
```

New is the `"ValueIndex"` which we employ to find out quickly if a certain value is alread know and what its repective number is. Unfortunately, this increases the size of the data container a bit. That may be only neglected if there are really only few different values compared to the number of keys that have to be stored. Here a short usage example:

```
n = 5;
rules = Association[Join @@ Map[Thread[# -> Total[#]] &, {Array[a, n], Array[b, n]}]];
dict = toDictionary[rules];
ByteCount[dict]
associateTo[dict, c[4] -> Total@Array[c, n]]
ByteCount[dict]
associateTo[dict, d[1] -> Total@Array[a, n]]
ByteCount[dict]
dict[c[4]]

5056

6336

6592

c[1] + c[2] + c[3] + c[4] + c[5]
```

Comment: Is there a way to generate the optimized dictionary "on-line" as entry bunches `a[i]` or `b[i]` etc become available, by adding them one after another? I would rather not construct the entire `rules` object before saving it to a better dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Do you intend to manipulate the association at some point? Otherwise I'd suggest defining a function:

```
dict[f_[_Integer]] := Plus@@Array[f, 3]
```

So `dict[a[2]]` gives `a[1] + a[2] + a[3]`. The number of terms in the sum is specified by the second argument of `Array`.

Comment: Problem is, in my actual example all the terms of the dictionary would be more complicated to generate and would create an overhead, which is why I'd like to save them in a dictionary in the first place.